# Insert empty space before appending div in jquery to a existing element?

Tags: jquery

How do I add a space between my comonpent that I am going to append to and my div that I am dynamically create.

I have some text in my cell and I am dynamically attaching a button to it using jquery. How can I insert a space between the text and the button in the below method so that there is a small gap between the text and the button.

```
onCellPrepared(e:any) {
    if (e.area == 'row') {
      if (e.cell && e.cell.type == "D") {
        $("<div /> ").dxButton({
          icon: 'fa fa-cog',
          type: 'default',
          height: '25',
          width: '30',
          onClick: function (e) {
            alert(e.rowPath);
          }
        }).appendTo(e.cellElement);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perpaps set margin-left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add backspace LIKE:

```
$("<div /> ").html('&nbsp;').dxButton({/*..............*/}).appendTo(e.cellElement);
```

or style for div:

```
 $("<div /> ").dxButton({/*..............*/}).css('margin-left'.'10px').appendTo(e.cellElement);
```